# Get full error message in Perl DBI module

Tags: perl, logging, error-handling, dbi

I have a Perl script like this:

```
use DBI;

eval {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:<database>", "<user>", "<password>") or die ($DBI::errstr);
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO WT_APPCERT_LH (STATUS, APPCERT) VALUES (?,?)");
    $sth->execute( "foo", "bar" ) or die($dbh->errstr);
    $dbh->disconnect;
};

my $err = $@;   
print "\$err => $err\n";
```

When I run it the console produce following output:

```
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-01722: invalid number (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 53 in 'INSERT INTO WT_APPCERT_LH (STATUS, APPCERT) VALUES (:<*>p1,:p2)') [for Statement "INSERT INTO WT_APPCERT_LH (STATUS, APPCERT) VALUES (?,?)" with ParamValues: :p1='foo', :p2='bar'] at C:\Temp\Perl-1.pl line 6.
$err => ORA-01722: invalid number (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 53 in 'INSERT INTO WT_APPCERT_LH (STATUS, APPCERT) VALUES (:<*>p1,:p2)') at C:\Temp\Perl-1.pl line 6.
```

I would like to store the **full** error message, but variable `$err` contains only `ORA-01722: invalid number (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 53 in 'INSERT INTO WT_APPCERT_LH (STATUS, APPCERT) VALUES (:<*>p1,:p2)') at C:\Temp\Perl-1.pl line 6.`

But I would like to get also `[for Statement "INSERT INTO WT_APPCERT_LH (STATUS, APPCERT) VALUES (?,?)" with ParamValues: :p1='foo', :p2='bar']` which is missing.

Any idea how to catch this additional information?

Comment: The chances are that the DBD::Oracle driver is producing that extra information, and the `$err` string is all that the DBMS tells the driver; the rest is determined by the driver from its own context information.

Comment: Have you tried using Try::Tiny to catch the error? It might get the full error message. You can also access `$dbh->errstr` after your `eval` block.

Comment: @simbabque, does not work, both return the same like `$@`

Comment: If you remove the `print` in the last line, do you still get he first line of output? I think that's on STDERR and is actually a _warning_ issued by DBI or the driver. Try to locally overwrite or hook the `$SIG{WARN}`, or use Capture::Tiny around the `execute or die` or the whole `eval` block to catch STDERR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for the PrintError attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#PrintError). It's enabled by default and is why the error is being logged to the console. It's also the source of the `DBD::Oracle::st execute failed:` prefix.

Then take a look at the [ShowErrorStatement attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#ShowErrorStatement). It's also enabled by default (in DBD::Oracle but not all drivers) and is the source of the `[for Statement "..." with ParamValues: :p1='foo', :p2='bar']` suffix.

Then take a look at the [RaiseError attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError). If that was set then the DBI would throw an exception (containing the message you saw logged to the console) when the error occurs. You could catch that exception and handle it however you want.

In general, I *strongly* recommend that all applications using the DBI enable RaiseError. It makes your applications more robust and you life *much* easier.

p.s. For advanced use-cases you *might* want to use look into the [HandleError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#HandleError) attribute, or in very rare cases, the [HandleSetError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#HandleSetErr) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Based on given comments and answer I found these solutions:

```
use DBI;

local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my $err = shift;
    print "\$err => $err\n";
};

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:<database>", "<user>", "<password>", { PrintError => 1, ShowErrorStatement => 1 } );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO WT_APPCERT_LH (STATUS, APPCERT) VALUES (?,?)");
$sth->execute( "foo", "bar" );
$dbh->disconnect;
```

and

```
use DBI;

eval {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:<database>", "<user>", "<password>", { RaiseError => 1} );
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO WT_APPCERT_LH (STATUS, APPCERT) VALUES (?,?)");
    $sth->execute( "foo", "bar" );
    $dbh->disconnect;
};
my $err = $@;   
print "\$err =>\n$err\n";
```

Comment: Your first solution will print `$err => ...` for *any* warning, not just those raised by DBI. It will also keep running even if there's a DBI error, which is almost never a good idea; you should pretty much always use `RaiseError`. To automatically log errors without having to wrap your code in `eval` blocks, use [`HandleError`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#HandleError).